# Is a pair of max functions equal to one max with two arguments?

Tags: optimization

Perhaps a trivial question but I'm wondering if the following equivalence always holds. Consider the maximization problem (P1):

$$\max_x\max_{y\in Y(x)} f(x,y)$$

And the problem (P2):

$$\max_{\{(x,y):y\in Y(x)\}} f(x,y)$$

Are (P1) and (P2) equivalent?

Comment: What is $Y(x)$?

Comment: @Dayton A general set of allowable values for $y$ that depends on the value of $x$.

Comment: Yes. Same as $\sum$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (assuming $\max_y f(x,y)$ is defined for each fixed $x$.) We suppress the notation $Y(x)$ and just assume that all $x,y$ are taken to be in the domain of $f$. Suppose that $(x_0,y_0)$ maximizes $f$.  Then $y = y_0$ maximizes $f(x_0,y)$, or else you could choose some $y_1$ with $f(x_0, y_1) > f(x_0, y_0)$, a contradiction.  So $f(x_0, y_0) = \max_y f(x_0, y)$.  Similarly, if there is $x_1$ with $\max_y f(x_1, y) > f(x_0, y_0)$ then there is $y_1$ with $f(x_1, y_1) > f(x_0, y_0)$, a contradiction.  So $$f(x_0, y_0) = \max_x \max_y f(x,y).$$